# load all cells before user scrolls in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a tableview that loads pictures using afnetworking, my problem is that the pictures don't load until the user stops at a particular cell. Is there a way to preload all cells in the tableview so that the pictures are ready for the user when they scroll down?

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code.

Comment: You are downloading that images in a synchronous way. You must use `NSURLSession` and blocks to download asynchronously